# Blog header layout is messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, blog

I was just looking at the latest [Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/18/podcast-115-stack-overflow-reads-mean-tweets/?cb=1) and noticed that the blog site's header is messed up.

When the page first loads, as shown in the image below, there are links that are covered up by the top bar.

[image: top of the page]

From inspecting the code, I can see that the links are supposed to go to the Company, Code for a Living, Insights, Engineering and Podcast pages. The only reason I noticed them is because you can see them sticking out a bit on the bottom. Also, if you look closely, you can see the Stack Overflow Blog logo from behind the black bar.

When you scroll down a bit, the black bar gets thicker, so you can't see any links sticking out, but I'm assuming the links are still hidden under the bar. Also, you can still see the words "Stack Overflow" very faintly through the black bar:

[image: scroll]

I was able to reproduce this bug in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Noted - looks like it has to do with the new nav that got shipped today. Investigating.

Comment: @JonChan Assuming it is related, because if I remember correctly, the blog top bar color was white until the new nav was rolled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. Blog was injecting some CSS that was unexpected from the topbar changes.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if this fix is an improvement. A 156px top bar is a TON of wasted screen space! A third of my screen is covered with the top bar and I am only able to view a small piece of the blog post at a time. And my screen size is pretty large. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2NAw.png) of my screen. I need to scroll so far down the page to start reading, and on my large screen, I only see the first two paragraphs in the beginning.